# Access array indices on x87 stack

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I'm having some difficulty with assembly syntax. In my assignment, we are required to pass a series of parameters to an x87 floating point register. One of those parameters is a double, and we're supposed to use this double as an array.

I've loaded it to the stack using **fldl 4(%esp)**, but now I have the task of accessing its array elements. I know and understand the syntax to manipulate integer arrays in x86, but I don't understand how to access the indices of an array while it's on an x87 stack.

Because it's the only thing on my floating point stack, I know that it can be found at **%st(0)**

Comment: A double has no array elements, unless you maybe mean the bytes it's made up of. In that case you don't have to load it into the FPU, just use it as a byte array normally. Otherwise please clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: The parameter that the assembly file is receiving from my C file is: double *Z. I need to access Z[i]. Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes, that means you have an array of doubles, that is more than one double. What do you want to do with them? And do you know how many there are?

Comment: I want to use each of them in a algebraic operation, and yes that number is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, your function gets a `double*` argument. Thus `4(%esp)` is a pointer to double, that is the base address where your array items are stored, at 8 bytes each. To access the `i`-th element, multiply `i` by 8 and add it to said base address. Assuming `i` is in `eax` you can load this element into the FPU like so:

```
movl 4(%esp), %edx   # load array base
fldl (%edx, %eax, 8) # load the array item whose index is in eax
```

Comment: Are you sure fldl loads a double?

Comment: @JensBjörnhager Yeah, confusing, isn't it. The suffixes for floating point go `s` for single precision, `l` for double precision and `t` for extended precision (80 bits). [Test program](http://ideone.com/VSUzfa)

Comment: Yet another piece of evidence that at&t syntax wasn't meant for humans.